# Add rows to a DataGridView in a different Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How do I pass DataGridView rows to a DataGridView on a different Form?

```
pos_receipt.PrintTable.Rows.Add(row.Cells("item_info").Value.ToString,
    row.Cells("Quantity").Value.ToString,
    row.Cells("Rate").Value.ToString,
    row.Cells("total").Value.ToString)
```

NB:
`pos_receipt` is the Form name where the DataGridView that I want to pass rows is located.

`PrintTable` is a data table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms)

Answer (score 0):

depends, if the form to which you want to pass the rows has been created in the form in which you are,
the only thing you have to do is a public function in the destination form and call it from you origin form. ej:

```
    dim DestForm as new FormName()
    DestForm.GetRows(RowOfMyGrid)
```

And in the dest form

```
    Public sub GetRows(Row as datagridviewRow)
        myDataGrid.rows.add(Row)
    end sub
```

If it is the other way round, and you want to pass the rows from the destination to the origin, you would have to do it using events