# How can I get a Boolean from form 2 to form1?

Tags: c#, winforms

how can I get a bool from class2 in Form2 to class1 in form1?

I've tried calling the variables, but that wasn't a success. Or i did something wrong

Class **Form3UpgradesGunSounds:**

```
    // If you double click, it will select the sounds
    private void Form3UpgradesGunSounds_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X > 36 && e.X < 336 && e.Y > 35 && e.Y < 93) // FireTankCannon100
        {
            _tankCannon100 = true;
        }
        else if (e.X > 336 && e.X < 670 && e.Y > 35 && e.Y < 93) // FireTankCannon120
        {
            _tankCannon120 = true;
        }
        this.Close();
    }
    public bool GetTankCannon100()
    {
        return _tankCannon100;
    }
    public bool GetTankCannon120()
    {
        return _tankCannon120;
    }
```

Class **Form1Game**:

```
    public void MoleShooter_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...  
        Form3UpgradesGunSounds fr3UpgradesSounds = new Form3UpgradesGunSounds();
        bool _f1tankCannon100 = fr3UpgradesSounds.GetTankCannon100();
        bool _f1tankCannon120 = fr3UpgradesSounds.GetTankCannon120();

        if (_f1tankCannon100 == false)
        {
            F1TankCannon100();
        }
        else if (_f1tankCannon120 == true)
        {
            F1TankCannon120();
        }
        // ... 
    }

    public void F1TankCannon100() { /*. Do something .*/ }

    public void F1TankCannon120() { /*. Do something .*/ }
```

**My question is** *How I can create and access to properties in `Form3UpgradesGunSounds` from the form `Form1Game`*

Comment: Try this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms)

Comment: ah oke, I will try my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Create a new property In `Form2` like this

```
  public partial class Form2: Form
    {
        public static bool BolleanProperty { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
```

2- in the [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) set property `BolleanProperty = true`

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{
    public static bool BolleanProperty { get; set; }
    static Form2()
    {
        BolleanProperty = true;

    }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

3- Now in `Form1`, you can access the property in `Form2`

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = Form2.BolleanProperty.ToString();
        }
```

**Updated my answer for the new contributor  [Luuk Scherjon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11544295/luuk-scherjon)**

To do this in your case,  you can follow these steps

1. Create tow [public properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in `Form3UpgradesGunSounds`.

   ```
   public bool TankCannon100 { get; set; }
   public bool TankCannon120 { get; set; }
   ```
2. In `Form3UpgradesGunSounds_MouseDoubleClick` event

   replace `_tankCannon100` & `_tankCannon120` with the properties was created

   ```
   if (...) // FireTankCannon100
     TankCannon100 = true;
   else if (...) // FireTankCannon120
     TankCannon120 = true;
   ```
3. Now in `Form1Game` > `MoleShooter_MouseClick` you can access the properties created in `Form3UpgradesGunSounds`

   ```
   public void MoleShooter_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       {
           // ...  
           Form3UpgradesGunSounds fr3UpgradesSounds = new Form3UpgradesGunSounds();

           if (!fr3UpgradesSounds.TankCannon100)
           {
               // do something 
           }
           if (fr3UpgradesSounds.TankCannon120)
           {
               // do something 
           }

           // ... 
       }
   ```